# How to Add Parameters in SQLite C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm using WPF and SQLite, I want to add new Parameters. I tried:

```
string _search;

private void txtSearchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _search = txtSearchBox.Text;
}

SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = music.db");
SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

private void btn_search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sqlite_conn.Open();
    sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "select Title from Song where Title=@title";

    sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add("@title",SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);  // ************ //

    sqlite_cmd.Parameters["@title"].Value = _search;


    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlite_cmd.CommandText,sqlite_conn);
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    datagrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

I got error on the line I ticked `// ******* //`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Always include the error message, verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong except that you are specifying a negative size against a string type column. Rather try like

```
 sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add("@title",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
```